# Display the warning dialog when a condition is satisfied in Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6

In my Wix Installer, I am searching for registry key for Adobe acrobat reader and displaying a warning dialog with "YES" and "NO" option. This dialog is supposed to display during the install sequence immediately after WelcomeDlg enabling user to "continue" or "exit" the installation if Adobe reader is not installed.

I am finding an issue in my code as the "AdobePrerequisiteDlg" does not honors the "ADOBEREADERINSTALLED" property, The dialog is getting displayed even when registry key exist.

The warning dialog "AdobePrerequisiteDlg" should only be displayed when Property "ADOBEREADERINSTALLED" is not satisfied (i.e. registry key does not exist),
But as of now that is not happening as I am able to see the dialog getting displayed everytime.

I tried many changes but not able to figure out where the problem exist.  Here is my code :

**Product.wxs**

```
<Property Id="ADOBEREADERINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="ADOBEREADERINSTALLED_REGSEARCH" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe" Root="HKLM" Type="raw"/> 
</Property>

<UIRef Id="PrerequisiteDialogUI" />
 <UI Id="UserInterface">     
      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />     
      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="AdobePrerequisiteDlg">1</Publish>     
 </UI>
```

**Components.wxs**

```
<Fragment>
 <UI Id="PrerequisiteDialogUI">         
      <Dialog Id="AdobePrerequisiteDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Software Requirements Incomplete">       
        <Control Id="YES" Type="PushButton"  X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"  Cancel="yes" Text="YES">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="NO" Type="PushButton" Text="NO"  X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" >
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Exit" />
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="1" Y="50" Width="340" Height="120" TabSkip="no">
          <Text>
           The following software requirements have not been met :
            
           Adobe Acrobat Reader                                      
           Do you wish to continue ?

          </Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Prerequisite for $(var.ProductName) is not installed." />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Adobe Reader 9.0" />
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />     
      </Dialog>      
    </UI>          
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Show Dialog="AdobePrerequisiteDlg" Before="ExecuteAction"> <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND ADOBEREADERINSTALLED]]></Show>     
    </InstallUISequence>
<Fragment>
```

Comment: What is the value of the property "ADOBEREADERINSTALLED"? You can find it out if you run your installer with the log: msiexec your.msi /l*v log.txt maybe it is x64 vs x32 bits issue?

Comment: @Nikolay : The value of ADOBEREADERINSTALLED is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe".  It doesn't seem to be a platform issue as I see that when custom dialog is removed and replaced with condition ( <Condition Message="Adobe is not installed"><![CDATA[ADOBEREADER9INSTALLED]]></Condition>). The message box honors the property. The custom dialog sequencing seem to have some issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to put the condition in the button click handler then?   <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="AdobePrerequisiteDlg">1</Publish>   <<< here you have "1" but probably should have your condition

Comment: @Nikolay I tried that but it is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need brackets or double NOT for the condition: `NOT (Installed AND ADOBEREADERINSTALLED)` OR `NOT Installed AND NOT ADOBEREADERINSTALLED`

And then. Do you see WelcomeDialog when you start your installer? Or AdobePrerequisiteDlg goes first? If second variant, you need to make some changes in your code. Try this:

1. Add reference to your custom dialog in your custom UI.
2. UIRef should point at custom UI, not the UI where custom dialog is described.
3. In your custom UI describe all variants and steps for dialogs. (see example below)
4. Condition statement should go inside Publish element.
5. InstallUISequence is not necessary.

**Product.wxs**

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="ADOBEREADERINSTALLED">
      <RegistrySearch Id="ADOBEREADERINSTALLED_REGSEARCH" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe" Root="HKLM" Type="raw"/>
    </Property>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <UIRef Id="UserInterface" />
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="UserInterface">
      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
      <DialogRef Id="AdobePrerequisiteDlg"/>

      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="AdobePrerequisiteDlg">NOT ADOBEREADERINSTALLED</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="Put_Next_Dialog_Id_Here">ADOBEREADERINSTALLED</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="AdobePrerequisiteDlg" Control="YES" Event="NewDialog" Value="Put_Next_Dialog_Id_Here"/>
      <Publish Dialog="AdobePrerequisiteDlg" Control="NO" Event="NewDialog" Value="UserExit"/>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
```

**Components.wxs**

```
 <Fragment>
    <UI Id="PrerequisiteDialogUI">
      <Dialog Id="AdobePrerequisiteDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Software Requirements Incomplete">
        <Control Id="YES" Type="PushButton"  X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"  Cancel="yes" Text="YES"/>
        <Control Id="NO" Type="PushButton" Text="NO"  X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" />
        <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="1" Y="50" Width="340" Height="120" TabSkip="no">
          <Text>
            The following software requirements have not been met :

            Adobe Acrobat Reader
            Do you wish to continue ?

          </Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Prerequisite for $(var.ProductName) is not installed." />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Adobe Reader 9.0" />
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
```